# Keycloack with OpenIdConnect redirecting to login page when request resource

Tags: node.js, rest, postman, keycloak

I'm studying Keycloak - openIdConnect.

### Context

I have three different Users settled in Keycloak.
I have user and admin Roles.
And user-app and admin-app Realm Roles.

- employee1 - user
- employee2 - admin
- employee3 - admin and user

I'm capable to generate access_token for all three users, via:

```
http://localhost:8080/realms/<MY_REALM>/protocol/openid-connect/token
```

I checked all the access tokens for the Users to grantee Roles are there, and they are.

I gotta a simple NodeJS application, using express server with json messages for each route. And protecting these routes with keycloak-connect for NodeJS as follows:

```
router.get('/anonymous', function(req, res) {
  res.status(200).json({
    messgae: "[HELLO ###ANONYMOUS###]"
  })
})

router.get('/user', keycloak.protect('user'), function(req, res) {
  res.status(200).json({
    messgae: "[HELLO ###USER###]"
  })
})

router.get('/admin', keycloak.protect('admin'), function(req, res) {
  res.status(200).json({
    messgae: "[HELLO ###ADMIN###]"
  })
})

router.get('/all-user', keycloak.protect(['user', 'admin']), function(req, res) {
  res.status(200).json({
    messgae: "[HELLO ###AALLL USER###]"
  })
})
```

### Behavior

I'm capable to get the /user and /all-user route mentioning employee1 and employee3 - access_token, they're users.

But when I get an admin access token and request the /admin and /all-user with this, Postman returns an HTML to login in Realm

[image]

In Postman console I was able to get an url that leads me to the realm login page, I enter the user and password but could not log in.

What am I missing to be able to access the resources using admin roles?

Answer (score 1):

You needs to set to match the public key between Keycloak and middle-ware(keycloak-connect) for JWT verification.

If not match it, the `keycloak-connect` makes this error.

```
Could not obtain grant code: Error: Grant validation failed. Reason: Misconfigured parameters while validating token. Check your keycloak.json file!
```

This is my demo steps and configuration

Keycloak: v18.0.2

realm: my-realm

client: my-client

port: 8080

Get public Key from my-realm's RS256(RSA) as this
[image]

It should match the `keycloak.json` in `keycloak-connect` project

```
{
    "realm" : "my-realm",
    "realm-public-key" : "MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAmhlpOZBxGjjQD0TTPOzSfmxFBTgpNHWwGOdLn4uK2Y7gLu4Z1BJCISIwfCqfEDmCBQO19X/caNMo0opbZl2qdEnsu7FGN90PWFaBUAS2DASRwhL2UZbuKOVLsUIXpDnDrAGP8ZR5nmQRkWaP7kYT7AErGrcBh4qfzXiw7aIEGI4e24MvK0L1AOVcv2ewPT4I2XAmjPcBsbcrMdrlU5kRYmuPm1Yix2J638VnvPuHRpqSt94e5LiBuo9NnP4pq6G8BZ29D02QKeV8zZcaD4N8clGSI2RMbr3mTp2hAZlNqRtFldpICfapWc5bnmR72UH8ZyV0b/D2LpqUFUirI2KJXQIDAQAB",
    "auth-server-url" : "http://localhost:8080/auth",
    "ssl-required" : "external",
    "resource" : "my-client",
    "public-client" : true
}
```

This is `index.js` in `keycloak-connect` project

```
const Keycloak = require('keycloak-connect')
const express = require('express')
const session = require('express-session')

const router = express()

const server = router.listen(3000, function () {
  const host = server.address().address
  const port = server.address().port
  console.log('Example app listening at http://%s:%s', host, port)
})

function get_user_name(token) {
    if (!token) {
        return 'Error';
    }
    const [header, payload, signature] = token.split(".")
    if(JSON.parse(Buffer.from(payload, "base64")).preferred_username) {
        return JSON.parse(Buffer.from(payload, "base64")).preferred_username;
    }
    return 'No User Name';
}

const memoryStore = new session.MemoryStore()

router.use(session({
  secret: 'mySecret',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  store: memoryStore
}))

const keycloak = new Keycloak({
  store: memoryStore
})

router.use(keycloak.middleware({
  logout: '/logout',
  admin: '/'
}))

router.get('/login', keycloak.protect(), function (req, res) {
    console.log('user login success!');
})

router.get('/user', keycloak.protect('user'), function (req, res) {
    console.log('hello user: ' + get_user_name(req.session['keycloak-token']));
})

router.get('/admin', keycloak.protect('admin'), function (req, res) {
    console.log('hello admin: '  + get_user_name(req.session['keycloak-token']));
})

router.get('/all-user', keycloak.protect(['user', 'admin']), function (req, res) {
    console.log('hello user & admin :' + get_user_name(req.session['keycloak-token']));
})
```

This is `package.json` in `keycloak-connect` project

```
{
    "name": "nodejs-keycloak-example",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "main": "index.js",
    "scripts": {
        "start": "node index.js"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "express": "*",
        "express-session": "*",
        "keycloak-connect": "^18.0.2"
    }
}
```

#### Keycloak Setup

Add client and assign redirect URL as same as in `keycloak-connect` project

```
http://localhost:3000/*
```

[image]

Add three users (all users password set `1234`)
[image]

Add two roles in `my-client`
[image]

Admin role assign two users as you mentioned it.
[image]

User role assigned two users (emplyee1 and employee3)
[image]

run project by 'npm start' after ran 'npm install'

Using `Chrome` or `Firefox` instead Postman.
Postman can't login by pressing `sign in` button.
It just HTML preview and not support full functionality.

[image]

I am using `Chrome` and `VS Code` terminal for `npm start`

login with employee1 `localhost:3000/user`
[image]

login with employee3 on `localhost:3000/all-user`
[image]

login with employee1 `localhost:3000/admin`
it will be access denied

[image]

You needs to logout the next user by `localhost:3000/logout`